# Running function without events in render

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with ReactJS and want to ask how functions works here. I have a class, function and render like this :

```
class MainTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: []
    };
    this.getREST = this.getREST.bind(this);
  }
  getREST() {
    console.log(this.props.str)
    axios.get(this.props.str)
      .then(res => {
        const results = res.data.results.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({results});
    });
    console.log(this.state.results);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Table hover striped bordered hover responsive size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.results.map(result =>
            <tr key={result.Name}>
              <td>{result.Name}</td>
              <td>{result.Name}</td>
              <td>{result.Name}</td>
              <td>{result.Name}</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

I can run `getRest()` function with button event using something like this

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} value="Click me" />
```

But how can i run `getRest()` function without any events, just in `render()`?

Comment: why do you need a function if you have to render it anyway??just write the code in render block.And it is preferred to write axios in componentdidmount instead of using any function

Comment: Lol, I'm noob. And it's not like in render i will got an infinity loop? I need to run it just once.

Comment: Loop because you use `setState` here, it calls `re-render` and another setState and again and again...
Check my answer

Comment: if you need to run it once then as i said above write the axios in componentdimount.it is an predefined method that will automatically get called after your component is just rendered

Comment: Ok, guys. I got it, ty for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fetch your data in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, not in `render`.

```
componentDidMount(){
      axios.get(this.props.str)
      .then(res => {
        const results = res.data.results.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({results});
    });
}
```

Comment: i think, `map` is not required here simply: `this.setState({results: res.data.results});` :)

Comment: @MayankShukla, Thank you